# React : new tab or refresh doesn't read localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm building a React app which requires authentification to use an API. So I keep the user token in my React context. Everything works fine as long as the user stay in the same session but, of course, whenever I open a new tab or refresh the current one, the context is lost. So I created a component that either stocks the token in localStorage (if there is a token) or retrieve said token from the localStorage.

I thought I had it figured out but... it doesn't work as expected. When I open a new tab, I am redirected to the login page (which is expected when there is no token).

I've checked what happens with some console logs and :

- when I log in a first tab, the token is saved to the localStorage.
- when I open a second tab, it looks like there is nothing stored in the localStorage.
- but if I save my code again AFTER opening the second tag (to add anything useless), then the localStorage is not empty anymore and I'm logged in the second tab too.

Here is my token handler component (called directly in App.jsx) :

```js
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";

import { DisplayContext } from "../context/DisplayContext";

export default function TokenHandler() {
  const {
    setCurrentUser,
    userToken,
    setUserToken,
    setTokenLimit,
    setUserRole,
  } = useContext(DisplayContext);

  const retrievingToken = () => {
    let stockDate = new Date();
    if (localStorage.getItem("mddTheme") && !userToken) {
      const stockToken = localStorage.getItem("mddTheme");
      if (stockDate.getTime() < stockToken.exp) {
        setUserToken(localStorage.getItem("mddTheme"));
        setCurrentUser(stockToken.sub);
        setTokenLimit(stockToken.exp);
        setUserRole(stockToken.aud);
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("mddTheme");
      }
    }
    console.log(
      "retrieving token : ",
      userToken,
      localStorage.getItem("mddTheme")
    );
  };

  const stockingToken = () => {
    if (
      userToken &&
      (!localStorage.getItem("mddTheme") ||
        localStorage.getItem("mddTheme") !== userToken)
    ) {
      localStorage.setItem("mddTheme", userToken);
    }
    console.log(
      "stocking token : ",
      userToken,
      localStorage.getItem("mddTheme")
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "token handler : ",
      userToken,
      localStorage.getItem("mddTheme")
    );
    // if (userToken !== "") {
    stockingToken();
    // } else {
    retrievingToken();
    // }
  }, [userToken]);

  return <></>;
}
```

Any idea why a new tab can't read the storage on opening ?

Comment: You shouldn't store an authentication token in local storage, use a secure Cookie instead.

Comment: That's not up to me, I do what my boss wants here ;)

Comment: Yes I understand.. You should maybe explain him/her that this is very unsecure. An authentication token shouldn't be handled by Javascript, only by your server, and used on client side with an http only cookie. And also I think using a cookie would solve your issue of session handling.

Comment: I already did but here we are ! So I'm looking for a localStorage solution.

Comment: I can't really see the problem with the localStorage access, but it could be useful to see the code that uses the present component to understand the problem. It could be problem like the `TokenHandler` component being resolved after the redirection mecanism. Also I think the retrievingToken and Stoking token function could be only one function with the relevant conditions, it'd be easier to read, and less error prone.